# Read Protect SD Card

Tags: permissions

If I access the Pi-SD from Ubuntu I can read all files which belong to pi. But I cannot read the files which belong to root. Can I make all the files of pi similar unreadable to Ubuntu (or any other OS). I would like to keep the file/folder permissions just make it non readable from outside.

[image]

And is this difficult to switch off for anybody?

EDIT:
I have a paygate in my software and would like to make it harder to be bypassed. I read, that it is basically impossible to secure code if the user has the device but I want to make it more difficult for a default user.

[How can I protect software on the Pi for commercial use?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/how-can-i-protect-software-on-the-pi-for-commercial-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using encryption, you can't.

Permissions can be used to make access difficult *on that machine* if the user doesn't need root and you're selliing either the hardware or an SD card image.  I'd just put the SD card in another linux machine, do `sudo su` and access it all.

If you start encrypting, you have to worry about where to store the keys, but unless the content is incredibly valuable (in which case you shouldn't be shipping it) a fairly crude encryption scheme will probably stop most users.